# Setting environment variables correctly in Vue.js application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So, I have the following two files in the root of my `vue.js` application:

`.env.development`:

```
NODE_ENV=development
VUE_WORDPRESS_API=LOCAL
```

`.env.production`:

```
NODE_ENV=production
VUE_WORDPRESS_API=PRODUCTION
```

I then have the following in my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --mode development",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
  },
```

So, I'm attempting to switch `modes` and therefore `env` variables depending on whether I am running `$ rpm run serve` or `$ npm run build`.

However, when running `npm run serve`, inside my application I am seeing that the environment variables aren't being set correctly:

```
// console.log(process.env.VUE_WORDPRESS_API) <= Undefined

if (process.env.VUE_WORDPRESS_API === 'PRODUCTION') {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.hostname
}

if (process.env.VUE_WORDPRESS_API === 'LOCAL') {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_WORDPRESS_API_LOCATION
}
```

I'm wondering, I must have something wrong with my env files? Are they named correctly? What am I missing?

Comment: Should it be `.env.local` instead of `env.local`?

Comment: @ittus Apologies, typo in my question - I have it as `.env.[mode]` in my source code...so that's not quite fixing things. (Have amended my question)

Comment: `process.env.VUE_WORDPRESS_API.LOCATION` is always `undefined`?

Comment: I would suggest you install and load `npm install dotenv`

Comment: @ittus Ahhhhh - here we go, the variables need to be `VUE_APP_WORDPRESS_API_LOCATION` and not `VUE_WORDPRESS_API_LOCATION` D'oh!